# Wrong indentation in python-mode with yasnippet, Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, indentation, yasnippet

Even when I open pure `emacs -Q` and a python file in it:

`|` - cursor

```
if smth:
|   print("asd")       # press TAB and cursor moves to "p" symbol, it's ok

if smth:
   |print("asd")       # press TAB and I get this:

if smth:
print("asd")           # press TAB and I get prev step
```

So `TAB` makes a cyclic change of indentation level. Which I absolutely don't want to.
If to use `smart-tab` problem can be solved. But `yasnippet` `(yas-global-mode 1)` brings it again.
And that's where I can't find why.

If you had this problem (python+yasnippet+correct indent) - please give me a tip.
Or just a link to a working config.

Latest Emacs (24.3.50.1)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  `(setq yas-indent-line nil)`    "Controls indenting applied to a recent snippet expansion.  The following values are possible:  - 'fixed' Indent the snippet to the current column; - 'auto' Indent each line of the snippet with `indent-according-to-mode'.  Every other value means don't apply any snippet-side indendtation after expansion (the manual per-line \"$>\" indentation still applies)."

Comment: No, the lines are still "jumping"

Comment: Which `smart-tab` is this?

Comment: Try setting `python-indent-trigger-commands` to nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of controlling the cycling  with <kbd>TAB</kbd> is to customize `python-indent-trigger-commands`.
The docstring of the variable states

> Commands that might trigger a `python-indent-line' call.

However it is not clear from the docstring that the variable can be
used to control cycling (actually I am not even sure if setting this
variable if the correct way of controlling indentation cycling). The
docstring of `python-indent-line` explains the purpose of this variable better

> When the variable last-command' is equal to one of the symbols
>   inside python-indent-trigger-commands or FORCE-TOGGLE is
>   non-nil it cycles levels indicated in the variable
>   python-indent-levels by setting the current level in the
>   variable `python-indent-current-level'.

So `(setq python-indent-trigger-commands nil)` (or you can just remove `indent-for-tab-command` from the list) can be used for disabling indentation cycling. There is
a slight disadvantage of this approach that you cannot use <kbd>TAB</kbd> indent code like the following where else
can either close `for` or `if`.

```
for ..:
    if ..:
        ...
        break
else:
    ...
```

You will have hit backspace before `else` to reindent it such that it
closes the `for` (by default it will be indented such that it closes the `if`)